# Jenkins -> source: not found

Tags: docker, jenkins

When i run this command by ssh into aws instance

```
docker run hello-world
aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ap-south-1 > ./login
source ./login
```

it output

> ```
> WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
> WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/ubuntu/.docker/config.json.
> Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store
>
> Login Succeeded
> ```

Which is success.
But when enter same command in jenkins like
[image]
output is 
[image]

1. I added user by

   > ```
   > sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins
   > sudo usermod -a -G docker user
   > ```

What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`source` isn't a standard shell command; it's not one of the "special built-in utilities" in the [POSIX.1 spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14).  Some shells happen to have a command named `source` but it's not required to be present.

There is a similar [standard command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18) `.` that executes a file in the context of the current shell.  If you're using the bash-specific `source`, you can usually just change that to the standard `.` without making any further changes

```sh
. ./login
```

Note that `.` searches `$PATH` for the file to run; it will not search the current directory unless specifically told to.  Also note that you typically only use `.` for scripts that have side effects like setting environment variables, and in a context like what you show where each command is running in a separate shell, this won't have longer-lasting effects.

Since the output of the `aws ecr get-login` command is a single `docker login` command that doesn't directly change the shell context, you can also just run it as a shell script

```
sh ./login
```

Comment: Perfect. I search that too but was trying only **.** But **sh ./login** work perfectly